# Database doesn't get updated

Tags: php, mysql, database

For some strange reasons, the database doesn't update. I can get the information, but it doesn't get updated when I click submit. Is there anything missing.

```
<?php
$dbhost = 'localhost';
$dbuser = 'root';
$dbpwd = 'ALLO';
$dbname = 'test_db';
$con = mysql_connect($dbhost, $dbuser, $dbpwd );
if(! $con )
{
    die("\$con: $con \nCould not connect: " . mysql_error());
}
$select_db=mysql_select_db($dbname);

$strquery = "SELECT * from Students WHERE Age='99'";
$results = mysql_query ($strquery);
$row = mysql_fetch_array($results);

?>
<body>

<table align="center">
    <tr>
        <td>
        <form id="update" name="update" method="POST" action="update.php">

        <table border="0" bgcolor="#6699CC" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="1">

            <tr bgcolor="#6699CC">
                <td colspan="2" align="center">Edit Student Records</td>
            </tr>

            <tr bgcolor="#FFFFFF">
                <td>F NAME :</td>
                <td><input name="fname" type="text" id="fname"
                    value=" <?php echo $row["FirstName"]; ?> " /></td>
            </tr>
            <tr bgcolor="#FFFFFF">
                <td>L NAME :</td>
                <td><input name="lname" type="text" id="lname"
                    value=" <?php echo $row["LastName"]; ?> " /></td>
            </tr>
            <tr bgcolor="#FFFFFF">
                <td>Age :</td>
                <td><input name="age" type="text" id="age"
                    value=" <?php echo $row["Age"]; ?>" /></td>
            </tr>

            <tr bgcolor="#FFFFFF">
                <td colspan="2" align="center"><input type="submit" name="Submit"
                    value="Update" /></td>
            </tr>

        </table>
        </form>
        </td>

    </tr>
</table>
```

**update.PHP:**

```
<?php
$dbhost  = 'localhost';
$dbuser  = 'root';
$dbpwd   = 'ALLO';
$dbname  = 'test_db';
$connect = mysql_connect($dbhost, $dbuser, $dbpwd);

if (!$connect) {
    die("\$connect: $connect \nCould not connect: " . mysql_error());
}
$select_db = mysql_select_db($dbname);

$strquery = "
    UPDATE Students
        SET FirstName = '" . $_POST['fname'] . "',
        LastName = '" . $_POST['lname'] . "',
    WHERE
        Age   = '" . $_POST['age'] . "'
";

$results = mysql_query($strquery);

header('location: displaytb.php ');
?>
```

I think it's the update that's not working, because everything else seems fine. displaytb.php just shows the database, but the content is not updated.

Comment: *PSA:* The `mysql_*` functions are [deprecated in PHP 5.5](http://php.net/manual/en/faq.databases.php#faq.databases.mysql.deprecated). It is not recommended for writing new code as it will prevent you from upgrading in the future. Instead, use either [MySQLi](http://php.net/manual/en/book.mysqli.php) or [PDO](http://php.net/manual/en/book.pdo.php) and [be a better PHP Developer](http://jason.pureconcepts.net/2012/08/better-php-developer/).

Comment: is it set to auto-commit or should you be using some transactions and a commit?

Comment: You update based on age ??? this is not good if two users have same age , use auto-increment id for users instead of age

Comment: Your `UPDATE` statement is vulnerable to SQL injection. Look into prepared statements.

Comment: FYI : This `update` will change the first name and last name of every students in your table having an age  that match `$_POST["age"]`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Inside  your sql query , there is a syntax error. After `lastname` shouldn't be any colon:

```
  $strquery="UPDATE Students SET        FirstName   = '". $_POST['fname']  ."', 
                             LastName   = '".  $_POST['lname']  ."' 
                          WHERE Age   = '".  $_POST['age']  ."' ";
```

Answer (score 0):

Your Where clause is using `Age` so, if you edit the `age` then where cause couldn't find anything.

And just like what JasonMcCreay Said, mysql_* is deprecated. Try to search for PDO or mysqli_*.